# a NSMutableArray got value when request data at ViewWillAppear, but can't get value at viewDidLoad, I used lazy-loading

Tags: ios, lazy-loading

Here is my code I have tried

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        NSLog(@"----------------------------%ld",self.studyArray.count);//value is nil
        [self createUI];
    }

(NSMutableArray *)studyArray{

        if (!_studyArray) {
            _studyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        return _studyArray;
    }

(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [self loadStudyData];
    }

(void)loadStudyData{

        if ([aa isEqualToString:@"10000"]) {

                NSDictionary *info =[responseObj objectForKey:@"info"];

                NSLog(@"%@",info);

                for (NSDictionary * dict in info) {
                    StudyModel * studyModel = [StudyModel new];
                    [studyModel setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
                    [self.studyArray addObject:studyModel];
                }
        NSLog(@"-----------------%ld",self.studyArray.count);// got an value
            }
    }
```

Comment: Does your word "no value" mean that count == 0? Count stand for the number of elements of the array, it should be 0 when there is no elements in it.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. `viewDidLoad` is called first, when the view controller is first loaded. It's only called once during the lifetime of the view controller.  `viewWillAppear` is always called after `viewDidLoad`. You assign a value in `viewWillAppear` but you can't get that value in `viewDidLoad`. Of course not. When `viewDidLoad` is called `viewWillAppear` has not been called yet.

Comment: And your `viewDidLoad` code doesn't do anything with your `studyArray` variable, so it is even *less* clear what you are talking about.

Comment: Finally, make your top level methods all have the same indentation level. By indenting all the methods after `viewDidLoad` more than `viewDidLoad` it makes it look like they are nested functions or something, and makes the code much harder to read. Following a consistent and coherent indentation style is quite important for readability.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks a lot! There was a part of coding I didn't copy, it looks like confused. In the ViewDidLoad, there is a part called [self createUI]. Then request the data in the viewWillAppear ,  and put them to studyArray. but when I want to send the value of studyArray to some label of creatUI , I found that studyArray contains nothing. I usually use viewDidload to loadView, and viewWillAppear to request Data, but this time it didn't work

Comment: So don't you think you should post ALL The relevant code if you want help debugging it?